# Random sort not working with --random_source=FILE

Tags: linux, file, sorting, random

I am experimenting with the sort command for Linux. I have file1:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

I tried:

```
sort -R file
```

The output of that command is always sorted randomly as expected

I then tried:

```
sort --random-source=/dev/urandom file1
```

and the command always has this output:

```
five
four
one
three
two
```

Why is the last sort command output always the same? Shouldn't it always be sorted randomly with this command?

Can I get an explanation on why this is occurring?

Answer (score 3):

`--random-source` option has no effect without `-R` option.
The result

```
five
four
one
three
two
```

is sorted alphabetical correctly. Therefore the result is always same.